# Android third party GUI widget vendors

Tags: android

In my MFC user interface programming days you could purchase all kinds of cool screen widgets from 3rd party vendors to integrate into your Visual Studio and use in creating your screens.  Fancy buttons, meters, control knobs, etc...  I can't seem to find anyone doing that for Android.  Does anyone know of any vendors selling stuff like that for programmers to use in Android projects?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems most of what is needed for android is open source. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for some cooler looking gui widgets than come built in.  Examples:  3-d looking buttons, rotary type knob that the user could twist with their finger, speedometer, stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe droidux is something you are looking for: http://www.droidux.com/
furthermore there are two open source ui projects called GreenDroid ( https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid ) and ActionBarSherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html ).

Let me know, if I could help you.

Comment: These are great examples of what I was looking for especially the droidux.  Anyone viewing this thread please add more as they come available.